# How to convert a list into a dataframe in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in a form of list. I want the values to be each row and i am trying to assign column names for each.

df1:

```
[['Lato', 85, 4, 12.0, 0.04633125, 160000, 0, 0, 0, 16, 15, 17]]
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

when i do print(df1) the below result is obtained.

```
Current Output:

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [[['Lato', 85, 4, 12.0, 0.04633125, 160000, 0, 0, 0, 16, 15, 17]]]
Index: []
```

```
Expected Output: #Assigning column names

font_label| font_size|len_words|letter_per_words|text_area_ratio|image_area|flag_present|detect_face_col| detect_logos |r |g |b
Lato      |     85   |    4    |      12.0      |  0.04633125   | 160000   |       0    |      0        |     0        |16|15|17|
```

I tried doing:

```
df1_update1 = str(df1.columns[0][3:])
df1_update2 = df1_update1.replace("]","")
```

but i dont know how to proceed after this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the output indicates that the column name is a list. How did you created df1?

Comment: There is a function that returns a output in excel format in form of list. Then when i am doing `df1 = pd.read_excel('Input.xlsx') ` and it gives the below dataframe. i am not allowed to change the previous function . All i can do is to try converting this into a dataframe to proceed with further steps. @Naveed

Comment: if you open it in excel, do you see any header? if there aren't any, then add header=None argument when reading excel. after it is in the dataframe, split it on comma